# Camera & Microphone does not work in webview_flutter package, even though the user grants permission for both

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview, webview-flutter

In my case I specifically need to use [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) for some reason, and in this package even after allowing camera and mic permission before entering the webview, inside webview camera and mic are not accessible. This case is specific for webview_flutter because when I tried [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview)  it could access the camera and mic.

Anyone have any solution regarding this problem? I can assure that the app has permissions for camera and mic as well, as app asks to grant the permission on early stage and is allowed to use both.